# Transform Linq to T-Sql Contains function

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq, contains

I have built a full-text index on human fullName parts, and want to improve my current results persons searching realization.

Currently i am using Linq Contains() methods, which are then translated into Sql 'LIKE' expressions.

But now i want to convert my Linq expression into T-Sql CONTAINS() function, which will use my full-text indexes to search faster.

How it is possible to implement this with linq?

My current linq expression looks like:

```
var query = from pi in context.PersonInfos                                    
        where
            (pi.FirstName.Contains(token0)
             || pi.LastName.Contains(token0)
             || pi.MiddleName.Contains(token0))
            && !pi.Disabled
        select pi;
```

Or maybe there is similiar to SqlMethods extension, that have methods, transformed to CONTAINS() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this is not supported in EF6, although there is a work around with interceptors.

http://www.entityframework.info/Home/FullTextSearch